# How can I create an in-memory test database when the table mappings are using other databases?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb, dbunit

I'm trying to create some tests for an application that uses Spring and JPA (with Hibernate).

I want to use an in-memory database so that I can check if everything is working without having to depend on the main development server (which is an old Sybase installation), and also will allow me to isolate better the tests functionality.

Problem is, there are a lot of tables that are mapped using `@Table("dbname..dbo.someviewname")` to access views from other databases.
So, I was trying to use HSQLDB with DBunit, but HSQLDB understandbly does not allow to create tables with dots in their names.

How can I do tests against that?

Should I give up of the in-memory thing and do tests using the main Sybase development server (risking to ruin it for the other devs :P)?

Comment: Its generally a bad idea to embed schema info (tables names/column names) in classes (unless only ever using one datastore ... for the full life of the app). Better to put it in orm.xml and have one for each datastore you may deploy your app to.

Comment: Good point! This is a legacy application with many tables, let's see what I can do about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `dbname.dbo.someviewname` HSQLDB likely extracts `dbname` as catalog, `dbo` as schema and `somewiewname` as table name.

HSQLDB do allow creating tables which have dot in their names. That can be done by treating table name as delimited identifier:

```
@Table(name="\"dbname.dbo.someviewname\"")
```

But you do not want to use that, because then how names are treated is changed also for Sybase. If you can have separate orm.xml for tests, then you can add following to orm.xml:

```
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
        <delimited-identifiers/>
    </persistence-unit-defaults>
```

It causes all database object names to be treated as delimited identifiers. Depending about your mappings and queries it can eventually work, but most likely you will face some problems. Likely best approach is not to have schema names in mappings and/or separate Sybase instance for tests.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know this can be done! I was actually able to get it working making all the mappings `@Table(name="tablename", catalog="catalogname")` and using a Spring bean to initialize the schemas for me (there are only a few).